# Reduce size of text_field on a form in rails and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm newbie and I'm developing an app with rails and bootstrap. I'm using this to generate a field on a form:

```
<%= d.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email" %>
<%= text_field_tag 'doctor[name][]', nil, :placeholder => "name" %>
```

and it works perfectly but I want to resize the height of it. I googled and I didn't found any good answer that fits.

Does anyone faced this issue?

Comment: In fact I need to reduce height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap v2, you should add this:

```
<%= d.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email", :class => "span5" %>
```

Note that the number in span class is referred to the size that you want to put.

If you're using this new bootstrap (v3 rc), you should check [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works, but is it possible to reduce height too? This is exactly what I need (but I didn't mention it, sorry). Thanks!

Comment: I found the way :) <%= d.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email", :style => "height:10px" %> Thanks anyway. ;)